# How to convert .jar file to .exe file?

Tags: executable, jar

I'm creating a Java program, and I need to test it on Windows. I know how to convert a .jar file to a .exe file on Windows, but the only Windows computer I know of is not mine. My friend will let me test the .exe file on it, but I can't download anything. Meaning no Launchj4. All that I need is an Ubuntu alternative.

Comment: There's no "Ubuntu alternative". Use a VM if you must.

Answer (score 2):

Java is known for its [write once, run anywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere) paradigm.
You probably are able to run the `.jar` file on windows too (I'm handwaving some minor differences in how a java program executes on each OS here).

It is likely that you can double click the `.jar` on a windows machine if you have java installed. From the command line, you can use:

```
> java -jar c:\path\to\your-java-program.jar
```

However, since this is not the place for windows questions, I'll refer you to this article instead for more details: https://windowsreport.com/jar-file-windows/